# While loop making array unavailable

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
function slotCalc(a, b) {
  var array = ["default"];
  while (a < b) {
    var obj = { test: "test" };
    array.push(obj);
    b++;
  }
  return array;
}
```

I can not understand why the array is not returned. If I remove the while loop, its returned as expected.

How can a while loop do this?

Comment: please add the parameter as well.

Comment: In case b is greater than a you endup in infinte loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error stems from `b++;` - so you (infinitely) increase `b`, but `a` does not change. So it's always `b > a` unless when you call this function with such parameters that`a >= b`.

Perhaps you wanted `a++;` instead; or, `b--;`